# Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) standards

Tags: ogc, interoperability

I was trying to understand about the OGC and OGC Standards but i got confused that are they provide standards like ieee or they provide standards that should be implemented with your application

i am looking for some one to give me details about the ogc,It is hard to understand it on there site

Comment: You need to expand your question to include which standards you are interested in, or what your application is going to do, or something to make this a question that can be answered.

Comment: I have a application that work on to the google maps. it is a tracking software now i wanted to know is it according to  (OGC) standards.

Comment: Google maps doesn't use any OGC standards other than KML (and even then their conformance is sketchy)

Comment: so it means that my application is not on ogc standards

Ok if i use geoserver and open layer then will my application   be on ogc standard

Answer (score 2):

> *if i use geoserver and open layer then will my application be on ogc standard*
>   It's not a problem about use or not use GeoServer / OpenLayers. OGC standards are about protocols like WMS, WFS, KML, WPS, ecc .. .so "things" that are on the server side of your solution. In this case if you use, for example, GeoServer to expose your data via WMS protocol your solution could be considered "ogc-compliant". OpenLayers is invariant because you use OpenLayers on client side of your solution but you could obtain the same result using for example using another javascript framework like Leaflet, commercial solutions like ArcGIS On Line or also using gis desktop solution open source or not.
>   Bye
>   Cesare

Answer (score 1):

For "how-tos on using and developing software that implements OGC standards" you could consult the [**OGC Tutorials**](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/tutorials) - I'm assuming anyone can create a login there.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94993/inspire-geoss-and-ogc):

The Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) exists to define interface standards such as the Web Mapping Service (WMS) standard, or Web Feature Service (WFS) standard. These are standards that define how programmers should create software to provide such a service.

So for example, OGC defines the WMS standard, programmers write a piece of software called MapServer that can create a WMS service according to this standard, lastly I as a user take this MapServer software, install it on a server add my data and create a service.

Similarly other programmers can write a client (for example QGIS or ArcMap) that understand the OGC WMS standard, such that my MapServer WMS service can be viewed and queried.

The IEEE Standards Association and the OGC operate in a similar fashion, but the IEEE standards are standards that apply generally at a lower level, for example deal with specifying standards that deal with hardware.

So to answer your OGC question, do `they provide standards like IEEE or` do  `they provide standards that should be implemented with your application` it is closer to the latter.